# Installation of l3backend package

Tags: packages

I am having toruble with the installation of the `l3backend` package.
I wanted to install the package because when trying to compile my file this error popped up:

`` ! LaTeX Error: 
File `l3backend-pdfmode.def' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,or enter new name. 
(Default extension: def)Enter file name:! Emergency stop.<read > } ``

I downloaded the package and tried to install the `l3backend.ins` in my windows console by going into the right directory and then typing

`latex l3backend.ins`

Then my console said that the command `latex` was written wrong or not found.

Any suggestions on how to install that package so that I can finally compile my thesis again??

Comment: Assuming miktex: go the miktex console, -> packages, there update the package list (click on the icon with the arrow) then search for l3backend and install it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I always tried to install it in Texmaker somehow. Problem solved!